# How to filter groups where the user is an admin?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, request, get, filtering

Making a request on the graph API in a user/groups node, I would like to bring only the data of groups in which the user is an administrator.
Can I pass some filter parameter to the administrator bringing only 'true' results? Or is there any other way to do this?

I've tried a few uses of .filtering, but none have worked. Other Meta APIs have filter defaults of admin_only, but I couldn't make use of them here.

Request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=name,id,first_name,last_name,email,picture{url},groups.limit(250){id,name,administrator}&access_token=xx
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/#parameters:

> `admin_only`
> boolean
> Default value: false
> Filter to get only groups admined by this viewer

Will need the `user_managed_groups` permission, without it I get an empty list.

Comment: Thanks for the support!

The user_managed_groups permission was discontinued in Graph API v3.0 in 2020, we are now in v15.0 and even though there is this admin_only parameter, it does not return any value. The only thing I managed so far was to pull 'id' and 'administrator' from all groups of a user and then delete administrator false, but it is a waste of processing and it is very slow.

Comment: @GabrielHenriques I am still able to request & grant that permission via Graph API Explorer (with the login dialog URL explicitly showing v15) - and with it, I get the list, without it is stays empty. If the permission has been deprecated and without it this doesn't work as described, then perhaps file a bug report and ask them what's up with that.

Comment: Weird, I can't find neither the user_managed_groups permission nor the admin_only parameter in my Graph API Explorer. I posted a bug call on Meta. Awaiting return. Thanks for the support @CBroe!